# Is there a way to use NASM syntax for inline assembly?

Tags: rust, nasm, inline-assembly, gnu-assembler

I really dislike the GNU Assembler syntax and I some existing code written with NASM syntax that would be quite painful and time consuming to port.

Is it possible to make the `global_asm!()` macro use NASM as the assembler or possibly make GAS use NASM syntax?

Comment: It's not. I'm using FASM myself (pretty similar to NASM), and i hate GAS. At least the standard syntax is intel. P.S. It's possible to write a proc macro for that, but...

Comment: Rust inline asm uses GAS `.intel_syntax noprefix` by default, right?  At least it's easier to port NASM to that than to AT&T.  OTOH, it's perhaps more error-prone because most NASM syntax is still valid in GAS, just has a different meaning.  But usually only with symbol names, like `mov rdi, foo` vs. `mov rdi, [foo]` vs. `mov rdi OFFSET foo` (or `lea rdi, [rel foo]` vs. `[rip+foo]`).  Normally you shouldn't be using symbol names directly in inline `asm` anyway, you should be using `%[]` operands that the compiler fills in, so it knows what memory you read+write.

Comment: If your code is large enough for this to be painful, perhaps just make it a function you call from Rust, instead of actually *inline*, so it can still be written in NASM syntax in a separate `.asm`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be able to change it but it seems as if GAS is the only viable option. In [Directives Support](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/reference/inline-assembly.html#directives-support):
'Inline assembly supports a subset of the directives supported by both GNU AS and LLVM's internal assembler, given as follows. The result of using other directives is assembler-specific (and may cause an error, or may be accepted as-is).'
Additionally,the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/reference/inline-assembly.html) states "Currently, all supported targets follow the assembly code syntax used by LLVM's internal assembler which usually corresponds to that of the GNU assembler (GAS). On x86, the **.intel_syntax** noprefix mode of GAS is used by default.'

This might be helpful as well https://github.com/Amanieu/rfcs/blob/inline-asm/text/0000-inline-asm.md